# PHP SEO optimized address and physical page address conflict

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have a static website that I am planning to move towards php. I will be using php to just load the navigation.htm and main contents page and combine to form a single html file.

1. Actual Page is here: http://abubakar.zxq.net/html/0007HorizontalAxisWindTurbineMadeWithPVCPipe.htm
2. How It is accessed through php:
   http://abubakar.zxq.net/index.php?page=0007HorizontalAxisWindTurbineMadeWithPVCPipe.htm

I want the page to look like 2 when site is addressed with URL in 1. It is needed to keep the already shared URLs remain working.

Here is how I defined httaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^html/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Kindly inform is it possible to do it in present form? I have a solution in mind that old files should be shifted to a new folder and the design php so that it works on old link. Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 2):

The regex you wrote doesn't match the first URL.

You need to add the dot character (because the URL ends up with ".htm"), try this :

```
RewriteRule ^html/([a-zA-Z0-9_\.-]+)$ index.php?page=$1
```

Comment: Dear Vince, I have implemented the advised change but there is no difference in results. Still I get the page located at physical address and not the one generated by php. Thanks for your suggestion,  anyway.